# Using grep to search along row in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the grep function to search along a row of a data frame in R, however it keeps returning "character(0)," is there something I don't know about searching along rows using grep?

I can see that what I am searching for is in the row, but grep isn't finding it.

Have tried supplying fixed=FALSE and ignore.case=TRUE

The command:

```
grep("string",df[1,])
```

I can easily use

```
which(df[1,]=="string")
```

But why does grep not find the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `grep` applies to a vector and not a `data.frame`:

**Data**

```
#> df=data.frame(col1=c("cat123","doggy"),col2=c("mydog","cat"),col3=1:2)
#> df
#    col1  col2 col3
#1 cat123 mydog    1
#2  doggy   cat    2

> is.data.frame(df[1,])
[1] TRUE
```

If you loop over rows of your `data.frame` with `apply`, you loop on vectors and the following works:

```
> t(apply(df,1,function(u) grepl("dog",u)))
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: You could also convert to a matrix `'dim<-'(grepl('dog', as.matrix(df)), dim(df))`

Comment: Always the best solution :) However can you refer to some link explaining clearly 'dim<-' ?

Comment: It is a different way of assigning instead of writing it in two steps.  ie. `m1 <- grepl('dog', as.matrix(df)); dim(m1) <- dim(df)`.  I don't have a link at the moment.

Comment: I understand the global concept but do not get it entirely, I guess it's working for other function.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the code of grep, you'll see the reason in the first line

```
 if (!is.character(x)) 
    x <- structure(as.character(x), names = names(x))
```

try that on a dataframe and see what happens